# Parsing Google Search Response Json Python requests. Regex Multiline

Tags: python, json, regex, google-custom-search

I want to transform the original response into a valid JSON, which I am able to do, but in a bit sloppy way.

This is the original response:

```
// API callback
google.search.Search.apiary2387({
 "cursor": {
  "currentPageIndex": 0,
  "estimatedResultCount": "4490",
  "moreResultsUrl": "http://www.google.com/cse?oe=utf8&ie=utf8&source=uds&q=ssh&start=0&sort=&cx=013305635491195529773:0ufpuq-fpt0",
  "resultCount": "4,490",
  "searchResultTime": "0.22",
  "pages": [
   {
    "label": 1,
    "start": "0"
   },
   {
    "label": 2,
    "start": "1"
   },
   {
    "label": 3,
    "start": "2"
   },
   {
    "label": 4,
    "start": "3"
   },
   {
    "label": 5,
    "start": "4"
   },
   {
    "label": 6,
    "start": "5"
   },
   {
    "label": 7,
    "start": "6"
   },
   {
    "label": 8,
    "start": "7"
   },
   {
    "label": 9,
    "start": "8"
   },
   {
    "label": 10,
    "start": "9"
   }
  ]
 },
 "context": {
  "title": "Pastebin Active",
  "total_results": "0",
  "facets": []
 },
 "results": [
  {
   "GsearchResultClass": "GwebSearch",
   "cacheUrl": "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:PBL2A25kpZoJ:pastebin.com",
   "clicktrackUrl": "https://www.google.com/url?q=http://pastebin.com/u/ssh&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiO4fjNpovMAhWBPxoKHYJXAS4QFggEMAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNHczEhDXdcUnRZhpArEeSiHfjwMJA",
   "content": "BitBucket - Backup your code in the cloud! Host unlimited private projects, for free\n. SIGN UP takes 10 seconds, and it&#39;s free! Guest&nbsp;...",
   "contentNoFormatting": "BitBucket - Backup your code in the cloud! Host unlimited private projects, for free\n. SIGN UP takes 10 seconds, and it's free! Guest ...",
   "formattedUrl": "pastebin.com/u/\u003cb\u003essh\u003c/b\u003e",
   "title": "\u003cb\u003eSsh&#39;s\u003c/b\u003e Pastebin - Pastebin.com",
   "titleNoFormatting": "Ssh's Pastebin - Pastebin.com",
   "unescapedUrl": "http://pastebin.com/u/ssh",
   "url": "http://pastebin.com/u/ssh",
   "visibleUrl": "pastebin.com",
   "richSnippet": {
    "cseImage": {
     "src": "http://pastebin.com/i/facebook.png"
    },
    "metatags": {
     "fbAppId": "231493360234820",
     "ogTitle": "Ssh's Pastebin - Pastebin.com",
     "ogType": "article",
     "ogUrl": "http://pastebin.com/u/ssh",
     "ogImage": "http://pastebin.com/i/facebook.png",
     "ogSiteName": "Pastebin",
     "viewport": "width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
);
```

And in order to extract the valid JSON I have to remove the JavaScript call, so I remove everything until the first `(` and I remove at the end, the `)`.

This is how I think it would work:

```
import requests
import re
import json

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1element?key=AIzaSyCVAXiUzRYsML1Pv6RwSG1gunmMikTzQqY&rsz=filtered_cse&num=1&hl=en&prettyPrint=true&source=gcsc&gss=.com&sig=432dd570d1a386253361f581254f9ca1&start=0&cx=013305635491195529773:0ufpuq-fpt0&q=ssh&sort=&googlehost=www.google.com&callback=google.search.Search.apiary2387'

resp = requests.get(url)

content = resp.content

formatted = re.sub(r'(.*\(|\);$)','', content , re.I|re.M|re.DOTALL)

formatted_json = json.loads(formatted)
for i, result in enumerate(formatted_json['results']):
    print formatted_json['results'][i]['url']
```

And this is what I had to add in order to make it work:

```
formatted = re.sub(r'// API callback', '', content)
```

I don't know why, since I am removing everything until I find the `(`, why doesn't it apply to all lines if I use the flag `re.M` ¿?

You can see `(r'(.*\(|\);$)','', content , re.DOTALL)` should work:

https://regex101.com/r/uN2wV4/3

(the option `/s` means `.` is also `\n` like `DOTALL`)

Comment: You have `$` in your regex, it matches the end of the line if `re.M` is specified.

Comment: note that the `$` is in the other possible match, after the `|`. It doens't work either without the `re.M`

Comment: That doesn't work either: `formatted = re.sub(r'(.*\(|\);$)','', content, re.DOTALL)`  it leaves the `API callback` at the begining of the string, dunno why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way: just removing this parameter from the request:

`callback=google.search.Search.apiary2387`

And the response is a valid Json.

Answer (score 1):

I created following [`regex`](https://regex101.com/r/uN2wV4/1):

```
(\{(?:.|\n)*\})
```

which instead of replacing, gets the contents between opening and closing braces.

So you can use this with [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search) to get what you need:

```
formatted = re.search(r'(\{(?:.|\n)*\})', content).group()
```

---

**UPDATE:** to use `re.DOTALL`

`re.DOTALL` is equivalent to the `/s` modifier (Updated [regex](https://regex101.com/r/uN2wV4/2)):

```
formatted = re.search(r'(\{.*\})', content, re.DOTALL).group()
```

Comment: Even simpler: `text = re.search(r'(\{.*\})', content, re.DOTALL)` works too

Comment: Yes it does. I didn't know how to use `DOTALL` in the regex tester link I have provided.

Comment: Now, it seems I could by using `/s` modifier at the end. Look at the updated link: https://regex101.com/r/uN2wV4/2

Comment: Yeaah it seems like the `/s` modifier is the same as  `DOTALL` its good to know. I still don't understand why this: `formatted = re.sub(r'(.*\(|\);$)','', content, re.DOTALL)` doesn't work though =(

Comment: `(?:.|\n)*` is one of the most unfortunate regex subpatterns, it is likely to cause performance issues with long inputs. Use `re.DOTALL` or ... `re.S` flags, or `(?s)` inside, at the beginning of  the pattern.